# App to override Django source

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to design a Django admin extension which requires minor changes in the source code, namely `django.contrib.admin.utils`, `django.contrib.admin.helpers` and `django.forms.forms`.

This is my first experience with creating Python/Django packages, and I wasn't been able to find any information on how to actually override the behavior of the Django source code using an external app, without changing the original files. In the ideal case, the app should be just listed among the `INSTALLED_APPS` or so. I would be really grateful for any directions.

UPD. The precise changes are:

in `django.contrib.admin.utils`:

```
def flatten_fieldsets(fieldsets):
    """Returns a list of field names from an admin fieldsets structure."""
    field_names = []
    for name, opts in fieldsets:
        for field in opts['fields']:
            if isinstance(field, (list, tuple)):
                field = filter(lambda a: a != None, field)
                **field_names.extend(field)
            elif field != None:
                field_names.append(field)**
    return field_names
```

in `django.contrib.admin.helpers`:

```
    class Fieldset(object):
        def __init__(self, form, name=None, readonly_fields=(), fields=(), classes=(), **settings=()**,
          description=None, model_admin=None):
            self.form = form
            self.name, self.fields = name, fields
            self.classes = ' '.join(classes)
            self.description = description
            self.model_admin = model_admin
            self.readonly_fields = readonly_fields
            **self.settings = settings**
            ...
```

in `django.forms.forms`:

```
class BaseForm(object):
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        "Returns a BoundField with the given name."
        try:
            field = self.fields[name]
        except KeyError:
            **if name != None:**
                raise KeyError('Key %r not found in Form' % name)
            else:
                field = Field(widget = TextInput(attrs={'style': 'visibility: hidden;'}))
        return BoundField(self, field, name)
```

Comment: Authentication / admin you can take a look here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. What exactly do you want to override?

Comment: @Lara thank you! I will take a closer look.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've updated the question with the wanted changes